# Which tools to learn to develop on Linux

Tags: linux, utilities

I've written a C-app on Linux, but I didn't know about "make" to auto compile, just write code with Vim and manually compile my app.
Which tools, utilities that a programmer should learn to be more productive on Linux?
I know git, diff, batch, make. Can you suggest more? thanks

(more specific, what tools for C, Python, Java programming)

PS: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your English is just fine, but I don't think this is really a SO question...

Comment: Agreed @keith.layne, probably looking in Programmers - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can I move it to Programmers exchange?

Comment: @HVNSweeting, your question might be too subjective even for Programmers (only 2/5 closers voted to migrate it). Maybe you can improve it before asking it there? Try being more specific, there's a very large list of tools for Linux development, and almost all of them will make you "more productive".

Comment: I expect a list of tool that programmers usually use on their development. I want to know what I don't know what are they. So how do I ask?

Comment: I think i found them here http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialSoftwareDevelopment.html#AUTOCONF thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could learn more by looking into how actual free Linux software are. So try for instance to retrieve and build from its source code some utility like e.g. [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/)

You could also use [GNU emacs](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/) instead of `vim`. It is a matter of taste (sort of "religious wars"). The main difference is that emacs users are doing all from emacs.

Comment: I compile software from within `vim` all the time: `!make` does the trick. But I don't read email or use IRC or surf the web from within `vim`... (I've got [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator) for that. :)

Comment: I just press my `F11` key under Emacs, it is bound to `M-x recompile`. Really a matter of taste and of definition (you don't recompile, you just run a shell command).

Comment: And you could also watch what other Linux developers are doing...

Answer (score 0):

You could try Netbeans an IDE for writing codes?

Comment: This is a matter of taste. For what it is worth, I know almost no GCC developer (the one working on the GCC compiler) using IDEs. I won't recommend using an IDE  (unless you call `emacs` an IDE).

Comment: Everyone I know personally uses `vim` or `emacs`, though I'm aware that there are Java programmers out there who like Eclipse or Netbeans because they are "better" at completing method names and the like.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: emacs is not an IDE, it's an OS in itself.